# Exclude a part of a jquery function only for IE?

Tags: jquery, function, internet-explorer

I have this function, which works great in all browsers and IE10, but not IE9 and below.
It would work if I exclude the effect-5. Is it possible to do so only for the older IE versions?

```
 function collage() {
    $('.Collage').removeWhitespace().collagePlus(
        {
            'fadeSpeed'     : 2000,
            'targetHeight'  : 200,
            'effect'        : 'effect-5',
            'direction'     : 'vertical'    
        }
        );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing browser detection, consider to use feature detection using [`modernizr`](http://modernizr.com).

> Unlike with the traditional—but highly unreliable—method of doing “UA
>   sniffing,” which is detecting a browser by its (user-configurable)
>   navigator.userAgent property, Modernizr does actual feature detection
>   to reliably discern what the various browsers can and cannot do. After
>   all, the same rendering engine may not necessarily support the same
>   things, and some users change their userAgent string to get around
>   poorly developed websites that don’t let them through otherwise.

In this way you can check if the browser support transitions (I think) and set the plugin accordingly, code:

```
function collage() {
    $('.Collage').removeWhitespace().collagePlus({
        'fadeSpeed': 2000,
            'targetHeight': 200,
            'effect': (Modernizr.csstransitions) ? 'effect-5' : '',
            'direction': 'vertical'
    });
};
```

Ref: http://modernizr.com/docs/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rhpK3/

Comment: thank you!
but I am already using modernizr and I still can't solve the problem.
I just wish to exclude this line for IE

Comment: What feature you want to detect? Eventually you can check the user agent with a regexp...